# Can not use where clause after using with clause in Laravel query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am writing a query using with and then where clause in laravel.

```
 $users = User::query()->with('roles')->where('name', '!=', 'customer')->get();
 return $users;
```

But where clause is not working here. Customers are not excluded. I am providing the snap shot of the query result.

[image]

Comment: `where()` clause is working here for your `users` table, not for the `roles` table

Comment: The `where` is only on the User query, not the Roles query. If you want it on the roles query, you'll need to pass it in as a closure.  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need **[`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)** :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$users = User::query()
          ->with('roles')
          ->whereHas('roles', function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('name', '!=', 'customer');
          })
      ->get();

return $users;
```

Comment: One question why we are using Builder before the query. Without declaring Builder it also works fine. @sta

Comment: @AbhijitMondalAbhi It's called type hinting. Object of class/interface is forced so no other object types can be provided. Safety measure. Also, `query()->` can be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you trying to filter relation data in base query.
Try smth like that:

```php
$users = User::query()->with([
  'roles' => function ($q) {
      $q->where('name', '!=', 'customer');
    }])
  ->get();

return $users;
```

[Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: This is excluding customers. But, it returns all Users which doesn't have the roll customer.